# Como ler um arquivo txt com tamanho dos campos fixos usando Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Ola, tenho um arquivo `.txt` que esta da seguinte forma:

```
"001","nome sobrenome","masculino","1231111322","email@msdsd"
```

Como eu posso ler ele usando `pandas` e criar um dataframe
Ele não tem cabeçalho e tem o tamanho fisco das colunas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode abrir o arquivo `.txt` e iterar suas linhas (separando as palavras presentes na mesma na vírgula):

```py
import pandas as pd

f = open("test.txt", "r") # Abre o arquivo txt para leitura
data = []
file_lines = f.readlines()
for line in file_lines: # Itera entre todas linhas do arquivo
    data.append(word.replace('"', '') for word in line.split(",")) # Separa as palavras na linha na vírgula, retornando uma lista com as palavras. Ex.: ["001","nome sobrenome", ...]

df = pd.DataFrame(data) # Cria o DataFrame
```

O DataFrame ficará da seguinte forma:

```
       0                 1            2             3                4
0   001   nome sobrenome   masculino   1231111322   email@msdsd\n
```

Comment: Matheus, muito obrigado, ja consegui criar o DF aqui, so uma duvida. Como voce faria para retirar as aspas, transformar o "nome sobrenome"para nome sobrenome.  Obrigado

Comment: Editei a resposta com a remoção das aspas duplas. A alteração foi na linha `data.append(...`, o que é feito ali é iterar cada palavra da linha e substituir as `"` na mesma por vazio

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente utilize a função `read_csv` passando o parâmetro `header=None` veja aqui a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Exemplo de entrada:

```
df = pd.read_csv("sample_data/arquivo_texto.txt", sep=",", header=None)
```

Saída:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1   nome sobrenome  masculino   1231111322  email@msdsd
1   2   nome sobrenome  faminino    2234157322  email@2sdsd
```

As colunas são uma sequencia de números agora, veja com `df.columns`

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

E para acessar o valor no dataframe:

```
str(df.loc[0][1])
```

Saída:

```
nome sobrenome
```